# Disable default shortcuts on a TabControl

Tags: .net, winforms, tabcontrol

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> are default shortcuts for the TabControl. They help in moving between adjacent tabs. I would like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageX</kbd> behaviour to work only for the outer tabs (tab1, tab2) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour for the inner tabs (tab3, tab4) when my focus is in the control (textbox here). For this, I need to disable the default behaviour. Is there some way to do this?

I looked at ProcessDialogKey and IsInputKey, but they seem to work only with single keydata. Modifiers are not handled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TabControl` has unusual keyboard shortcut processing, they are reflected to the `OnKeyDown()` method.  This was done to avoid it disturbing the keyboard handling for the controls on a tab page.

You'll have to override the method.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your `Form`.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyTabControl : TabControl {
  protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Tab | Keys.Control) ||
        e.KeyData == (Keys.PageDown | Keys.Control)) {
      // Don't allow tabbing beyond last page
      if (this.SelectedIndex == this.TabCount - 1) return;
    }
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note the code above doesn't disable all the tab control hotkeys: you can still use **CTRL+TAB+SHIFT** etc. Change the if statement to below: `if ( ke.Control && (ke.KeyCode == Keys.Tab || ke.KeyCode == Keys.Next || ke.KeyCode == Keys.Prior)) return;`

Comment: That shortcut key tabs backwards.

Answer (score 4):

As written, Hans Passant's answer didn't work unless you were on the last page of the tab control. I want something the doesn't allow the shortcuts on any of the tabs. The code below also incorporates AZ's additional logic to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd>. Hopefully this version makes the overall logic a little more clear:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    internal class NoTabTabControl : TabControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Intercept any key combinations that would change the active tab.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            bool changeTabKeyCombination =
                (e.Control
                    && (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab
                        || e.KeyCode == Keys.Next
                        || e.KeyCode == Keys.Prior));

            if (!changeTabKeyCombination)
            {
                base.OnKeyDown(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like left- and right arrow keys also changes tab.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `tabpageX.Enabled` property to `false` in your code when required. Then using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will not be able to Select the `tabpageX`.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> at first look created a havoc on my application. I used this to save my assets.