# Disable Ctrl + Tab in Windows Forms tabs

Tags: winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable default shortcuts on a TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952839)

How can I prevent users from using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between tabpages?

Comment: why on earth would you want to do something like this??

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts are a pretty basic accessibility feature - I would hate it if I was expecting to be able to use them, and then found out that some programmer out there decided not to let me.

Comment: You can use Tab Controls to emulate Wizard functionality, whereby each tab represents a page or step of the wizard. The tab headers themselves are hidden and navigation between the tab pages is controlled by buttons (Back and Next). If there is further functionality associated with the buttons (e.g. prerequisites for showing a page), I can imagine that you would not want the user bypassing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Stack Overflow question *[Best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in a Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-winforms)*.