# winforms panels as slides?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one Form1 in Windows Forms and want to show and hide different sets of controls, depending on which button the user clicks. As you find it for example in many option dialogs, categories on the left-hand site, the actual config options on the right-hand side. And I don't want to use tabs for this. What's the control I need?

Comment: You might check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257581/designing-windows-form-with-multiple-panels-how-to-hide-one-panel-like-a-ps).  One excellent suggestion is to make a tab control and hide the tabs.

Comment: Tree control and group panels?

Comment: @SandraWalters: Thanks. It is strange there is no standard solution to this problem. You find multi-layer forms in every third GUI..

Comment: Try looking at [this control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226381/Scrolling-Panel)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it:

1. Add a panel control to the right side and dock it as Fill
2. Create user controls that will fit within the panel control.  These user controls should contain the different groupings of controls that you want to display.
3. When the event happens on the left side (e.g. someone clicks a button or tree item), dynamically load a particular user control on the right side as shown here:

   ```
   while (Panel1.Controls.Count > 0) Panel1.Controls[0].Dispose();
   Panel1.Controls.Add(new MyUserControl());
   ```

You can then create a variable that casts Panel1.Controls(0) to your actual control type and work with it however you want:

```
    MyUserControl myControl = (MyUserControl)Panel1.controls(0);
```

You will likely want to change Panel1.Controls(0).Dock to style Fill as well.

Comment: I don't know whether this is the way it's commonly done, but I have personally written several complex programs Windows Forms applications this way, using either an Outlook-style collapsing control or a tree view on the left side and displaying the content in an expandable partition on the right.  It's a flexible design and works pretty well.  You also get a nice separation of concerns from having the various Windows Forms controls encapsulated within the user controls.

Comment: I have done it exactly the same way in projects of mine using SplitPanel and TableLayoutPanel for containers. You can event stack the controls and control their visibility in the Z-plane using Control.SetChildIndex(control, zIndex), this way you do not need to clear the main panel.

Comment: I do it the same way, by starting with a SplitPanel and then layering on either TableLayoutPanel or FlowPanel controls as called for by the design.  Then, in the appropriate place, I drop a regular panel to hold the dynamic user controls (which I usually call MainPanel or something similar).